Changing focus point on a Nikon D5600 in dynamic mode?
When I select dynamic focus (for example 9) I expect to see a 3x3 grid in the eyepiece before I've depressed the the button and after pressing button to the first position I expect to see the single point it actually focused on.
But now, in any of the 9,21,39 modes all I see is a single point directly in the center, it never moves nor does it ever show me a grid.
I swear when I first got this camera (new) I would see a grid, press the button, and possible points would change red momentarily.
Have I imagined this or is there a reason the preview grid does not display in the viewfinder?
